# Como faço para armazenar dados e não excluir quando o programa acaba?

Tags: python

Como que eu faço para que quando um dado é armazenado, ele não seja excluído ao programa acabar?
por exemplo:

```
LISTA = ['Morango', 'Abacate']
ADD_ITEM = input('Digite algo que deseja adcionar:')
LISTA.append(ADD_ITEM)
```

Enquanto o programa estiver a rodar,o valor fica armazenado em `LISTA`.
No entanto,ao termino do programa, o valor armazenado simplismente some.
Como devo resolver isso?

Já tentei o `open`, mas como não sei usar muito bem, acabei falhando.

Já usei todo qualquer tipo de lista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa salvar essa lista num arquivo, e ler esse arquivo quando você rodar o programa (se ele existir).

A parte mais difícil de fazer isso é traduzir os seus dados pra um arquivo e vice-versa. Vou mostrar 3 métodos aqui, numa progressão mais ou menos didática, espero que ajude.

**MÉTODO 1**

No seu caso, que é só uma lista de strings, podemos organizar de um jeito simples salvando um arquivo com cada elemento em uma linha. Você teria então:

```
LISTA = ['Morango', 'Abacate']
```

Que vira o arquivo "LISTA.txt":

```
Morango
Abacate
```

Vale lembrar que uma quebra de linha é na verdade um caractere especial `\n`, então na verdade o conteúdo do arquivo é:

```
Morango\nAbacate\n
```

Com isso em mente, vamos pro código. Tá bem comentado pra você seguir:

```
import os

LISTA = []

## Carrega a lista do arquivo
# Abre o arquivo (se ele já existe)
if os.path.exists("LISTA.txt"):
    # Abre o arquivo para leitura ('r' -> read)
    file = open("LISTA.txt", 'r')
    # Lê o arquivo linha por linha e coloca na lista
    for item in file.readlines():
        LISTA.append(item[:-1]) # Esse [:-1] tira o último caractere, um "\n"
    # Fecha o arquivo
    file.close()

## Seu código
ADD_ITEM = input('Digite algo que deseja adcionar:')
LISTA.append(ADD_ITEM)

## Salva a lista no arquivo
# Abre o arquivo para escrita ('w' -> write)
file = open("LISTA.txt", 'w')
# Itera a lista e escreve cada item no arquivo
for item in LISTA:
    # O str() converte o item em uma string
    # O '\n' no final é uma quebra de linha, pra cada item sair numa linha
    file.write(str(item) + '\n')
# Fecha o arquivo
file.close()
```

**MÉTODO 1++**

É possível utilizar alguns recursos do Python pra enxugar esse código, comentei o que mudou:

```
import os

LISTA = []

## Carrega a lista do arquivo
# Abre e fecha o arquivo (se ele já existe)
if os.path.exists("LISTA.txt"):
    with open("LISTA.txt", 'r') as file:
        # O resultado dessa função já é a lista que a gente quer
        # Deixa o "\n" e não adiciona na hora de escrever
        LISTA = file.readlines()

## Seu código
ADD_ITEM = input('Digite algo que deseja adcionar:')
LISTA.append(ADD_ITEM+"\n") # adiciona o "\n" só nos itens novos

## Salva a lista no arquivo
# Abre e fecha o arquivo
with open("LISTA.txt", 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(LISTA)
```

**MÉTODO 2**

Agora, caso você queira guardar coisas mais complexas do que uma lista, esse processo começa a ficar penoso demais. Então pra isso existe o módulo `pickle`, nativo do Python. Esse módulo pega variáveis e salva elas em um "picles", um arquivo binário que pode ser aberto depois e recuperar toda a estrutura dos dados, sem se preocupar em fazer essa tradução na mão.

Fiz um exemplo usando o `pickle`, bem comentado também:

```
import os
import pickle

LISTA = []

## Carrega a lista do arquivo
# Abre e fecha o picles (se ele já existe)
if os.path.exists("LISTA"):
    # Abre o arquivo em modo de leitura binária 'rb'
    with open("LISTA", 'rb') as file:
        LISTA = pickle.load(file)

## Seu código
ADD_ITEM = input('Digite algo que deseja adcionar:')
LISTA.append(ADD_ITEM)

## Salva a lista no picles
# Abre o arquivo em modo de escrita binária 'wb'
with open("LISTA", 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(LISTA, file)

## Não é possível ler o picles no editor de texto,
## então imprimo os valores aqui pra ver
print(LISTA)
```

Comment: Valeu mano, ajudou muito!

Answer (score -1):

Depende do propósito da sua aplicação.

Pode ser serializando em um arquivo .txt se for apenas texto ou em .xlsx e similares, se for pra organizar os dados em uma planilha. Caso opte por usar um BD, tem o SQLite que é mais básico e salva os registros localmente.

Independente da escolha, são boas opções para se praticar e aprender, caso você esteja começando em programação.